# Iterating over all possible bit permutations

Tags: c++, c++11, generator, bit, input-iterator

Say I want to iterate over all bit sequences (for lack of better name) in the range `0000`-`1111`. When I want to scale it up to 24 bits, I won't be able to simply compute all possible permutations beforehand; I'd need to compute them on the fly.

How can I generate the permutations on-the-fly (like Python generators with `yield`) using something like `InputIterator` or a decorated while loop?

Comment: How about counting from 0b0000 to 0b1111 ?

Comment: Can't you just do a loop for(int i = 0; i < 1 << 24; ++i) ? It'd go over all required bit combinations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you can use an int (which is stored as bits anyway at it's core), just bound your loop to only iterate up to the widest int that the space would allow (in this case 24 bits). Starting at 0 and adding successive ones will implicitly step through every possible bit combo.

No need to precompute or store anything. here is a 4bit example:

```
for(unsigned long int cnt = 0; cnt < 16; cnt++) DoSomething(cnt);
```

In this case DoSomething(const unsigned long int&) could simply map the bits and perform the action you're looking for.

If your implementation supports it, use uint_32t type for an explicit and exact width.

Comment: If you're googling and you find this, don't forget to use `long` for `i`!

Comment: You should usually prefer unsigned when working with bits. Also, since you want some minimum number of bits, I would prefer to use `uint32_t` (or one of its variants) rather than `unsigned long`.

Comment: uint32_t is an excellent update, but it may be implementation dependent. will update.

Comment: In my loop I added `bitset<24>(cnt)` to convert it into a proper index-accessible bitset